# Redshift connection to a database

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbeaver

I am trying to create a redshift connection through dbeaver and I'm getting at connection attempt timed out message; however I was able to create a connection through the console using the same credentials that I'm using to connect through dbeaver, any ideas what might be causing this issue/ [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a network configuration issue.  This kind of timeout issues often comes when there is no route from the computer you are logged into to the Redshift cluster.  A route clearly exists for the console since you can connect but the system running dbeaver likely doesn't.

Start looking at the network configuration that would impact this connection.  Is the dbeaver system inside the VPC?  Is the redshift cluster public?  Is the redshift port open in both directions?  How are the security groups configured?

If you need help is configuring AWS networks the stackoverflow community can help.  Just add details about the network config.

Comment: Bill Weiner thank you!